# Changes made to contents.css file of ckeditor not loading

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, firefox

In my firefox 43 if i put a long text in ckeditor, I get different result in firefox and chrome. In chrome work-wrap works and breaks the word by creating a new line.But in firefox an horizontal scroll bar appears and send the text outside of the window's confinement.to   prevent this behaviour i applied the following css to ckeditor's contents.css file.But the changes are not loading.

**Can browser's cache prevent the changes from being applied?please help.**

**can i use php to respond to css change using time related functions.**

**I didn't link the contents.css file to my page.It remains inside ckeditor file**

[image]

```
body
{
    /* Font */
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
    font-size: 12px;


    /* Text color */
    color: #333;

-ms-word-break: break-all;
-ms-word-wrap: break-all;
-webkit-word-break: break-word;
-webkit-word-wrap: break-word;

word-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap:break-all;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
white-space: pre-wrap;

hyphens: auto;
    /* Remove the background color to make it transparent */
    background-color: #fff;

    margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

solved it with this piece of code:

```
    CKEDITOR.addCss( 'body {word-break:break-all;}' );
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
      fullPage: true
    })

;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding the following to contents.css on line 21:

```
.cke_editable {
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.6;
word-break: break-all;  <-- add this
```

Comment: Very strange. It works for me on both firefox and chrome. Could you send me the link to your website?

Comment: thanx for trying to help:) solved the issue.Posted it as an answer below